# Sybase - Can we find out list of tables, stored procs which are not being accessed/used in last 1 year?

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

We are in process of migrating an existing legacy system and would like to retire some DB components so that we dont need to worry about data etc. We shut down many processes which were obsolete and now we think we should cleanup our database so that we know the exact data objects we need to worry about.

The database is in sybase 15. Can we find out list of tables, stored procs, triggers etc which are not being accessed/used in last 1 year using some sybase system tables?

Comment: You may be able to through the Monitoring tables.  Also, there is a way to find [unused indexes in the database](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20022_1251/html/monitoring/CIHJGIII.htm) - if a tables indexes are not being used, there's a good chance that it's not being accessed.

Comment: you can find out unused indexes, but the requirement you have, I don't think its possible to find out unused object (by user ).

Comment: You may have a look at [Understanding_the_audit_tables](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sag1/html/sag1/sag1865.htm)